# How to add the different styles when hover on various elements under single <a> tag using JavaScript or jQuery or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is my code where am facing issue to add styles:

```
<div class="panel">
  <a href = "link">
    <img src="abc.jpg"> 
    <h5>Description text</h5>
  </a>
</div>
```

Requirement:

1. When hover on the image then H5 text-color can changed in blue color.
2. When hover on H5 text then the text-color can changed in red color.

Please welcome your fixes either in JavaScript or jQuery or CSS

My try is:

```
$(".panel a").hover( 
function() { $("h5").css("color","red"); } ); 
$(".panel a").hover( 
function() { $("img").css("color","blue"); } );
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Hi @Sfili_81, Please find my try
                                                                           
  $(".panel a").hover( function() { $("h5").css("color","red"); }, function() {
                $("h5").css("color", "blue");
            } ); 

$(".panel a").hover( function() { $("img").css("color","blue"); }, function() {
                $("img").css("color", "blue");
            } );

Comment: don't add code inthe comments, please update your question

Comment: Hi @Sfili_81, I got answers from our friends. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is what you wanted to achive but i suggest if you dont need `a` to wrap whole content rather than just in `h5` for click then replace `h5`with `a`
as your current layout needs more work to achive simple thing

```css
a {text-decoration:none;}
h5 {text-decoration:underline;color:black;width:max-content;}

h5:hover {
  color:red;
}

img:hover + h5 {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
<a href = "link">
<img style="height:120px;" src="https://i.ibb.co/hLZrDv0/Hitman-3-artwork.png"> 
<h5>Description text</h5>
</a>
</div>
```

**here is my suggested layout**

```css
a{color:black;}
.panel > * {display:block;width:max-content;}
a:hover {
  color:red;
}

img:hover + a {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
<img style="height:120px;" src="https://i.ibb.co/hLZrDv0/Hitman-3-artwork.png"> 
<a href = "link">Description text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Amir,   Thanks for your solution and its awesome!!.  Your suggested layout is not possible in my requirement.

Comment: ya i can understand thats why i provided solution in both way your wellcome

Answer (score 1):

The `:hover` state is the best way to fix this for the hover over the `h5` and `img`

```
h5:hover {
   color: red;
   transition: .2s; // makes the color change smootly and not static.
}

img:hover + h5 {
    color: blue;
    transition: .2s;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jelle, Thanks for your solution and only one concern is  On-hover image style is not working and rest are fine!!

Comment: I'll edit the code for you, there is an easier way. Please check it out

Comment: Sure @Jelle, I am waiting for your solution

Comment: Done, Same as the answer you had approved already. Good luck with your project!